# Countdown by difference between two date in xdan/flipcountdown jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datetime, countdown

I am using xdan-flipcountdown jquery plugin as a counter.
I have two date variables:

```
start_date=1396-10-04
end_date=1396-10-08
```

I want to calculate the difference between two date variables and count down it's value
I use method like this:

```
$(".timer").flipcountdown({
        size:'sm',
        beforeDateTime: end_date
});
```

but it is not worked?
how can I Calculate the difference and then count down it's difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this.i use JDateTime php class then convert shamsi date to Gregorian date.then use:

```
            $(this).flipcountdown({
                size:'sm',
                beforeDateTime: $(this).attr('data-time-end')
            });
```